# WinJS - ListView event bubbling

Tags: html, knockout.js, winjs

I have a listview with "iteminvoked" listener. List contain one input text column for quantity. When i click on textbox for entering quantity "iteminvoked" event fire.
How can i stop event when click on textbox in listview.

I have bind list with "WinJS.UI.ListView" control and "WinJS.Binding.Template".

below is my list,

```
<div id="productsview" class="productsview win-selectionstylefilled"
                         data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView"
                         data-win-options="{
                        selectionMode: 'multi',
                        itemTemplate: select('#customProductListTemplate'),
                        layout: { type: WinJS.UI.ListLayout },
                        loadingBehavior: 'incremental',
                        pagesToLoadThreshold: 2,
                        pagesToLoad: 2,
                        automaticallyLoadPages: true
                    }"
                         data-bind="winControl: {
                        incrementalDataSource: productSearchViewModel.customProductManager,
                        iteminvoked: productInvokedHandler,
                        loadingstatechanged: { AfterLoadComplete: '#productResultZero', OnLoading: indeterminateWaitVisibleForProducts },
                        selectionchanged: { eventHandlerCallBack: productListSelectionChanged, appBarId: '#commandAppBar' },
                        }">
                    </div>
```

below is my template,

```
<div id="customProductListTemplate" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
    <div class="listViewLine" data-win-bind="title: ProductName">
        <div class="ratio1">
            <a class="h4" href="#" data-win-bind="text: ItemId"></a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h4 class="ellipsis wrapText" data-win-bind="textContent: ProductName"></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="ratio1 textRight">
            <input type="number" data-win-bind="value: SelectedQuantity" data-bind="clickBubble: false" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer with the help of [this post](http://www.davidezordan.net/blog/?p=7329)

change in my template,

```
<input type="number" class="win-interactive" data-win-bind="value: SelectedQuantity; onclick: clickInTextFunction;" />
```

change in my modal class,

```
public clickInTextFunction: any;
constructor(odataObject?: any) {
this.clickInTextFunction = WinJS.Utilities.markSupportedForProcessing((ev) => {
            ev.stopImmediatePropagation();
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
data-bind="click: function(data, ev) { ev.stopImmediatePropagation(); }, winControl: {
                        incrementalDataSource: productSearchViewModel.customProductManager,
                        iteminvoked: productInvokedHandler,
                        loadingstatechanged: { AfterLoadComplete: '#productResultZero', OnLoading: indeterminateWaitVisibleForProducts },
                        selectionchanged: { eventHandlerCallBack: productListSelectionChanged, appBarId: '#commandAppBar' },
                        }"
```

As the click handler is bound first, it should intercept the click event and through `stopImmediatePropagation` prevent other click handlers bound to the same element from firing.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but it not works. the "iteminvoked" event called even after adding your code.

Comment: Hmm. Do you have the source for that binding?

Answer (score 0):

I did a simple test case, and turns out that `clickBubble: false` must be combined with `click` binding to work properly:

```
<article>
    <div>
        <input type="text" data-bind="click: inputClick, clickBubble: false" />
    </div>
</article>
```

JS:

```
(function(){
    var $div = document.querySelector("div");
    $div.addEventListener("click", function(){
        alert("div clicked");
    }, false);

    function ViewModel() {
        this.inputClick = function(){};
    }

    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(), document.querySelector("article"));
}());
```

Above example works as you expect - click on input cancel bubbling and handler attached to `<div>` is not triggered.

You can try it out http://jsfiddle.net/jggo7zw7/

Comment: I have already try this but it not works. Actually I'm using template.